# I can only do manual partitions in the Lubuntu Installer?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

[This is what I see in the Lubuntu installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST8kg.jpg)

[I also can only see my USB drive in the drop down menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJbK1.jpg)

Hello. I’m trying to dual boot Lubuntu on my computer with Windows 10. On the partitions windows in the installer, it only says Manual Partitions.  What do I do to install Lubuntu with Windows?

Comment: If it isn't "seeing" the internal drive(s) then likely you need to change the drive mode in UEFI from whatever is set - "RAID", "Intel RST", ... - to the supported mode AHCI. But you need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing modes.

Comment: Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/i-can-only-do-manual-partitions-in-the-lubuntu-installer/3125/  and as I said before; providing release details is always helpful.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you! Changing to AHCI worked!

Answer (score 1):

I did what @ChananAuto said. I changed to mode to AHCI, then I got the option to dualboot in the Installer.